# console.log isn't showing useState info

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I'm using Firestorage with React. Basically what i'm trying to do is after user uploaded multiple images into Firestorage, it will then add the URL of the image into Firestore database as shown

[image]

However, when I tried adding it into the field value it's showing nothing instead. So I went ahead with console.log(urls) to see what's wrong with my code, and in the console.log it's not showing anything in the array.

Here is my code:

```
const [productImages, setProductImages] = useState([])
const [urls, setUrls] = useState([])

function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    const promises = []
    setLoading(true)
    setError("")

    // PRODUCT IMAGE UPDATE IF NOT NULL
    if (productImages !== null) {
        const promises = []
        productImages.map((image) => {
            const uploadTask = storage.ref(`products_images/${image.name}`).put(image);
            promises.push(uploadTask)
            uploadTask.on(
            "state_changed",
            snapshot => {},
            error => {
                console.log(error);
            },
            async () => {
                await storage
                    .ref("products_images")
                    .child(image.name)
                    .getDownloadURL()
                    .then(urls => {
                        setUrls((prevState) => [...prevState, urls])
                    })
            }
            )
        })
        Promise.all(promises)
            .then(() => console.log("Images > ", urls))
            .catch((err) => console.log(err));
      }

    Promise.all(promises)
      .then(() => {
        //history.push("/")
        //TRIED PUTTING HERE AS WELL BUT IT'S STILL SHOWING NOTHING
      })
      .catch(() => {
        setError("Failed to update account")
      })
      .finally(() => {
        setLoading(false)
      })
  }

const handleChange = (e) => {
      for (let i=0; i<e.target.files.length; i++) {
          const newProductImages = e.target.files[i]
          newProductImages["id"] = Math.random();
          setProductImages((prevState) => [...prevState, newProductImages]);
      
    }
  }
```

In my code, you can see where I put `console.log("Images >", urls)`. It's returning nothing instead of all the images URLs. However, when I put `console.log("Images >", urls)` at the very end of all functions, before return() it will show all the URLs. What can I do to make it show the images URLs on submit button?

---- EDIT ----

I tried using useEffect to upload data into firestore database once it detect urls state has something, that achieved what I wanted but it's duplicating. It detected that the state has changed twice, because it has two images being uploaded. Is there any way to fix it so that it will upload only once after multiple images are stored in the state?

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (urls.length) {
        const newProduct = {
            product_category: productCategoryRef.current.value,
            product_name: productNameRef.current.value,
            product_images: urls,
            product_postedby: currentUser.email
        }
        db.collection("products").add(newProduct);
    }
  },[urls])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using either `then()` or `async`/`await`, but not both in the same piece of code. While they *can* be used together, it requires that you know more about their functioning.

The code gets significantly simpler if you *only* use the promise that `put` returns, and then chain the calls to `getDownloadURL` after that. As far as I can see, it turns into something like this:

```
if (productImages !== null) {
    const promises = productImages.map((image) => {
        const ref = storage.ref(`products_images/${image.name}`);
        return ref.put(image))
            .then(() => ref.getDownloadURL());
    });
    Promise.all(promises).then((urls) => {
        setUrls(urls)
    })
}
```